# Is it possible to make DataGridViewRow.Cells support methods like Any or All?

Tags: c#, datagridview, lambda

Say, I want to check if any `Cell`'s `Value` is `null` in a `Row` from a `DataGridView`.The code using `foreach` works.

```
        foreach (DataGridViewCell c in row.Cells)
        { 
            if (c.Value == null)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                MessageBox.Show("empty cell");
            }
        }
```

I tried method `Any` to replace `foreach`,but didn't compile:

```
        if(row.Cells.Any(c => c.Value == null))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show("empty cell");
        }
```

Is there anyway to make it support method `Any`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast them:

```
if (row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Any(c => c.Value == null)) {
  // code...
}
```

The DataGridViewCellCollection doesn't specify the generic type, so a cast is required.  See [Enumerable.Cast`<TResult>` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx):

> The Cast(IEnumerable) method enables the standard query operators to be invoked on non-generic collections by supplying the necessary type information. For example, ArrayList does not implement IEnumerable, but by calling Cast(IEnumerable) on the ArrayList object, the standard query operators can then be used to query the sequence.

Comment: Hi,thx for answering. Your code works.I noticed that `DataGridViewCellCollection` has implemented interface `IEnumerable`. Can you give a little bit more about why such cast is still needed?